# Return fake jqXHR from custom Ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several methods that wrap the `$.ajax()` method and return its jqXHR, but I need to force fail before even calling the original `$.ajax()` and still allow to use success/error methods of the result.

```
//just a very simple example, actuall code is more complicated
$.rpc = function(method, args) {

    if (!method || 'string' === typeof method ||) {
        return false; //PROBLEM - cannot use success/error handlers!
    }

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rpc',
        data: { method: method, params: args },
    }); //AJAX()
};

//usage:
$.rpc(loginMethod, credentials).success(gotoProfile).fail(gotoLogin);
//if loginMethod is for any reason undefined it crash instead of calling fail handler
```

So I use this helper method, since the jqXHR is created directly inside the Ajax method:

```
$.ajax.getFailed = function(message) {
    var
        jqDef = new $.Deferred(),
        jqXHR = jqDef.promise();

    jqXHR.success = jqXHR.done; //deprecated  $.ajax methods
    jqXHR.error = jqXHR.fail;

    jqDef.reject.defer(1, jqXHR, [jqXHR, message]);
               //defer is from extJS, alternative to setTimeout

    return jqXHR;
};

$.rpc = function(method, args) {

    if (!method || 'string' === typeof method ||) {
        return $.ajax.getFailed('Missing method');
    }

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rpc',
        data: { method: method, params: args },
    }); //AJAX()
};
```

Is this code OK or is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Does your approach work? If it works, I guess it is OK :)

Comment: I've made a jQuery plugin that supports this approach: https://github.com/nothrem/jQueryProcess (see the last part of the README).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) reveals a `beforeSend` option that would allow you to cancel the request before it's sent by returning `false`.

```
$.rpc = function(method, args) {
    var beforeSend = function () {
        return method && 'string' !== typeof method;        
    }

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rpc',
        data: { method: method, params: args },
        beforeSend: beforeSend
    }); 
};
```

Comment: This seems to work for fail case correctly and answers the original question. But in the meanwhile I've created similar method getDone() which I use in case the data are already cached on client - and this method cannot cancel the AJAX while calling the success handlers.